# Unable to Upload a Large File to S3 Bucket

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I deployed my Django app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and tried to upload some csv files. It seems that a small csv file works fine (1000 lines) but with a large csv file, it cannot be uploaded (1,000,000+ lines). Any idea how to fix that?

Besides, uploading a large file succeeded from my local host but failed when on the Elastic Beanstalk URL.

Working in Python and Mysql.

Comment: Post the error you're seeing in logs / cli output to your question, that will help SO diagnose the problem.

Comment: It seems that the error I got when I deploy the app on heroku is `sock=client at=warning code=H27 desc="Client Request Interrupted"` which means it is time out. But I'm pretty sure that I upload the file directly to the S3 bucket. This is what I did: `AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'xx.storage_backends.MediaStorage'`